# ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I´m getting this severe error in my Rails 4 app and because of that my connection to my database is lost.

```
F, [2015-12-23T18:06:22.875935 #13919] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.009 seconds)):
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `loop'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `wait_poll'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:136:in `block in poll'
  /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:146:in `synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:134:in `poll'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:423:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__285615481658568074__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:74:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:490:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:361:in `process_client'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/server.rb:254:in `block in run'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `call'
  puma (2.10.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:96:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I´m trying to debug it but it´s quite complex. I don´t know where the issue is coming from.

I read this post before [ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801185/activerecordconnectiontimeouterror-could-not-obtain-a-database-connection-wit) and there is an answer from @railsana that fits one possible scenario of mine.

I have some kind of batch processes that makes lots of queries called from a model (outside controller) by an scheduled task. I tried to follow their suggestion and added this code to this functionality, however the issue is still there.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  # your code
end
```

Just in case it´s a relevant information, my rails app is running in a Puma server and my database is MySQL.

Any suggestions, what can it be, or how to debug it? The bug is really fatal because my application cannot handle any query.

**UPDATE:**
Answering to the questions:
1. In production I have configured a pool with 5 connections in config/database.yml.
2. My Puma server startup log:

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 2.10.1 (ruby 2.1.2-p95), codename: Robots on Comets
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: production
* Daemonizing..
```

.

Only one worker is started.

**UPDATE 2:**

Checking puma.stderr.log I found this kind of error logs:

```
{ 70238458077400 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  70238458077400   job:
  70238458077400     Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob "90s" {}
  70238458077400   error:
  70238458077400     70238458077400
  70238458077400     Net::ReadTimeout
  70238458077400     Net::ReadTimeout
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:152:in `rbuf_fill'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:134:in `readuntil'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/protocol.rb:144:in `readline'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:39:in `read_status_line'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:28:in `read_new'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1408:in `block in transport_request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `catch'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1405:in `transport_request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1378:in `request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:65:in `perform'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:42:in `block in request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:78:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:78:in `block in do_request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:76:in `do_request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/net_http.rb:33:in `request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi.rb:161:in `request'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi.rb:133:in `post'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in `block in call_with_logging'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in `log'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in `call_with_logging'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:54:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:560:in `block (2 levels) in getAvailabilities'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:544:in `each'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:544:in `block in getAvailabilities'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:13:in `each'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:530:in `getAvailabilities'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:65:in `updateAvailabilities'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/app/models/secretary.rb:182:in `block in getBoatsAvailability'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/app/models/secretary.rb:181:in `getBoatsAvailability'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb:29:in `block in <top (required)>'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:224:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:224:in `do_trigger'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:269:in `block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:272:in `call'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:272:in `block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'
 70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:258:in `loop'
  70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.3/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:258:in `block in start_work_thread'
} 70238458077400 .
```

This is the portion of code that is sending throwing this exception (I think not catched exception):

```
 # This method is in a model invoked by an scheduled task rufus-scheduler that is executed every 90 seconds.

 def self.getBoatsAvailability
    if Rails.env.production?      
      require 'service'
      # This line was added to try to fix this problem (I read this approach in another post link above)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        Service.getAvailabilities(false)
      end
    end
 end

def self.getAvailabilities(isMonthly)
    @logger.debug "Importing availabilities..." 

    # Savon is a service to communicate with SOAP web services    
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "url", 
                          log_level: :debug,
                          log: true,
                          pretty_print_xml: true)
    mmkCompanies = Mmk::Company.select("id").where(loading: true).order("id") 
    createdAt = Time.now        
    @logger.debug "getAvailabilities Before each company."
    for mmkCompany in mmkCompanies do
      lastModifiedReq = Mmk::Availability.find_by_sql(["SELECT max(a.created_at) as max_date
                                                        FROM mmk_availabilities a, mmk_resources r 
                                                        WHERE a.resource_id = r.id
                                                        AND r.company_id = ?", mmkCompany.id]).first.max_date                
      (0..1).each do |i|
        year = Time.now.year + i        
        message = {'in0' => credentials, 
                   'in1' => credentials, 
                   'in2' => credentials,
                   'in3' => mmkCompany.id,
                   'in4' => year,
                   'in5' => true,              
                   'in6' => lastModifiedReq}

        @logger.debug "getAvailabilities Before client call."   
        response = client.call(:get_availability_info, message: message)
        @logger.debug "getAvailabilities After client call."    
        availabilitiesXML = response.to_hash[:get_availability_info_response][:out]
        availabilitiesParsed = Nokogiri::XML(availabilitiesXML)
        availabilities = availabilitiesParsed.xpath("//reservation") 
        @logger.debug "getAvailabilities Before transaction."             
        Mmk::Availability.transaction do
          @logger.debug "getAvailabilities Transaction opened."   
          for availability in availabilities do 
            id = availability["id"]           
            # More parse parameters unrelevant code              
            mmkAvailability = Mmk::Availability.find_or_initialize_by(id: id)                   
            mmkAvailability.update(resource_id: resourceId, status: status, blocks_availability: blocksAvailability,
                                   date_from: dateFrom, date_to: dateTo, base_from: baseFrom, base_to: baseTo, 
                                   option_expiry_date: optionExpiryDate, last_modified: lastModified, created_at: createdAt)
            mmkAvailability.save            
          end
        end
        @logger.debug "getAvailabilities After transaction (closed)?."
      end
    end
    @logger.debug "Availability imported successfully."
  end
```

This line in exception:

```
`70238458077400       /home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/lib/mmk_service.rb:560:in `block (2 levels) in getAvailabilities'`
```

correspondes to:

```
response = client.call(:get_availability_info, message: message)
```

My analysis (althouth not everything is matching for me), is:
- The method getAvailabilities is sending a webservice SOAP request to a third party system. 
- Sometimes for some reason, this connection is lost or the third party service doesn´t response and Net::ReadTimeout exception is thrown.
- This exception is not caught. And a database connection (and this is the part I don´t understand) keeps opened.
- When this issue happens 5 times, the number of pool connections is 0 and I got the main issue.

Comment: Have you specified a connection count in `config/database.yml`? How many threades puma runs (you can see this in console after running web server)?

Comment: Are you logging slow queries in your MySQL server? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html. You can also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620662/mysql-see-all-open-connections-to-a-given-database to see if it sheds any light on which connections are staying open.

Comment: Please, see my updates with answers.

Comment: @andrykonchin please, see my updates.

Comment: When count of threads (16) is greater than open connections to the database (5) you can encounter such kind of issue. Increase connections count to 16 and check again.

Comment: @andrykonchin please see my updated analysis. I think the problems come because there is an exception that should be caught? Anyway, I will try with your suggestion increasing my pool connections. But I´m worry about the consecuences of this? What about the performance?

Comment: @Midwire please see my updates.

Comment: @andrykonchin This is what I read regarding connection pools in rails docs: It will also handle cases in which there are more threads than connections: if all connections have been checked out, and a thread tries to checkout a connection anyway, then ConnectionPool will wait until some other thread has checked in a connection. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: I see, are you able to connect to database (with console client for example) after receiving this error? It will indicate where is the issue - on database side or on the application one.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to database with a database client.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this problem I would start by adding an exception handler (`rescue` clause) to the `self.getAvailabilities` method.

```
def self.getAvailabilities(isMonthly)
  ... # existing code goes here

rescue Net::ReadTimeout => err
  # I would use pry to put a breakpoint here and see what is keeping the DB connection open.
  binding.pry
end
```

Use the `pry` gem to insert a breakpoint in the handler. Once the Savon call times out it should hit that breakpoint. Then you can use the REPL to determine who is holding the connection, and probably close it. See here: [How to find current connection pool size on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528371/how-to-find-current-connection-pool-size-on-heroku).

If the exception is not caught I would change the `rescue` line to catch `StandardError` instead of `Net::ReadTimeout` and try again.

Comment: Hi, I already added the exception handler. I thought just capturing the exception I wouldn´t lost the connection. I don´t know where the connection is created, but if the exception is captured, and the program ends normally, the connection should not be lost. I don´t create the connection manually, Rails is doing it. I´m quite desperated, because the system goes continually down. I need to debug the connections, but I don´t know how to use pry.

Comment: Pry is a <strike>wonderful</strike> essential tool. You can find out more here: https://github.com/pry/pry. Essentially, it will drop you into the Rails console at the `binding.pry` line and allow you to execute code right there. You can then examine things and even change things. I would use the `binding.pry` example above and then run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` from the mysql console to learn about the active connections. Then figure out how to close them. Of course this is treating the symptoms instead of the disease, but it may help you gain the insight you need to solve the problem at the source.